# Large Number of Rows Incrementing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is the quickest way to create 50,000 Rows
Incrementing Numbers: CCC100200 - CCC150200?

Dragging down is taking forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) function.

```
=ArrayFormula("CCC"&SEQUENCE(50001,1,100200))
```